# A good introduction to Elliptical Curves from an advanced High School background.

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves

I am looking for a manageable introduction to elliptical curves from a High School background. I am willing to read material. I'm aiming for a introductory undergraduate level of understanding of such curves and their properties. I want to do a little personal research into these curves and maybe explore some simple properties on my own. I came across them because I heard that this was the math behind some cryptographic methods and also the blockchain concept uses this.

Thank you

Comment: You should really learn the more basic higher math first, that way you'll get more out of any textbook. Have you taken complex analysis yet? Try it.

Comment: @mtheorylord I would love to but don't have the time right now. I don't know if you recognize it but I study in the IB curriculum and was considering this for a Math HL IA. (it's like a mini project where you 'explore' or 'investigate' a topic.)

Comment: I think it may be very difficult, and even discouraging, to try to tackle such a stuff without first having *at least* some basics in abstract algebra and complex analysis...not to mention some mathematical maturity. Don't do that to yourself. Better, imo, try to tackle the undergraduate basic material needed to understand elliptic curves.

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't know if you recognize it but I study in the IB curriculum and was considering this for a Math HL IA. (it's like a mini project where you 'explore' or 'investigate' a topic.) This is mainly because they seemed interesting when I looked it up. I think some of the complexity and difficultly was hidden behind the relatively simple introduction found on Wikipedia.

Comment: Nop, I don't recognize it, but I just read now that is a baccalaurate studies, and to me this sounds like high school level. Anyway, the very basic stuff needed there involve group theory, advanced analytic geometry, real (and pretty soon also complex) analysis, etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah well. I guess I'll go look for something interesting in real analysis. Do you have any starting points? Something that is accessible by someone of my level and could feasibly be the topic of a mini project of sorts.

Comment: Since you have an interest in math related to cryptography, you might also be interested in focusing on the algorithms behind RSA or Diffie-Hellman key exchange. The math is much simpler than what would be needed for elliptic curves, and should be well suited for a high school student. They also introduce some basic concepts which are used throughout number theory and algebra such as modular arithmetic and group theory.

Comment: @TobErnack Thanks, I'll look into it. I actually did initially arrive at RSA but my only concern was that it's a topic that has been exhausted by others before me. (I don't know if you recognize it but I study in the IB curriculum and was considering this for a Math HL IA. (it's like a mini project where you 'explore' or 'investigate' a topic.)) So I guess I will rack my head trying to find an original approach to this. I know this is kinda going off topic, but calculus is of great interest to me as well.

Comment: @TobErnack However, due to its sheer size and vastness, I get hopelessly lost trying to find a challenging yet doable idea for such a project. I either end up on the research page of some university where I don't understand a word or I find something too elementary. Do you know a good 'middle ground' that you might point me towards. It would be of immense help.

Comment: Try googling ["elliptic curve" AND "honors thesis"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elliptic+curve%22+%22honors+thesis%22) (or substitute something else for "elliptic curve" if you want to consider other topics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*

Authors: Silverman, Joseph H., Tate, John T.

May still be a bit advanced but would probably be the most approachable.

Comment: Is this accessible to a HS student (IB diploma math HL if you recognize it)

Comment: I thank you for the answer though and I will definitely look for a copy and try getting through it.

Comment: The authors state "Our main goal in doing this has been to write a textbook in a technically difficult field which is "readable" by the average undergraduate mathematics major."

Comment: Well I think this is the closest I'll get, I'll take a look. Thanks